# R Coxph Timescale at Risk

Tags: r, survival-analysis, cox-regression, survival, ggsurvfit

```
library(survival)
set.seed(1)
STARTAGE = sample(20:60, 100, T)
ENDAGE = sample(5:20, 100, T)
STATUS = sample(0:1, 100, T)
X1 = sample(1:3, 100, T)
X2 = sample(1:10, 100, T)

MODEL1 = survfit(Surv(ENDAGE, STATUS) ~ 1)
plot(MODEL1)
MODEL2 = survfit(Surv(ENDAGE, STARTAGE, STATUS) ~ 1)
plot(MODEL2)
```

In this example I build survival curves. When you plot you see risk starts at 0 but it should start at STARTAGE as this is the first time when the ID is at risk...How Do I Edit This?

Comment: Can you just use `xlim` in `plot` to define the x-axis limits you want for the plot? Something like: `plot(MODEL2, xlim = c(min(STARTAGE), ...`?

Comment: @Ben i think yes but are the results affected though since the at risk time start early that the startage?

Comment: Adding `xlim` will only affect how the plot looks, not the model or results. Have you tried it out? Try varying the limits with your example, and see if this provides what you are looking for.